# why cocos compile doesn't work after importing to eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I created new `cocos2d-x` project by terminal, `cocos new -p com.study.example_01 Example_01`.

Right after new project is made, I compiled it by typing in terminal, `cocos compile -p android`, and it compiles successfully.

But after I imported to eclipse, with nothing is changed, I tried to compile it as before, it fails with error => Using Eclipse Project : `C:\[FILE DIRECTORY]\proj.android. GoogleInc.:GoogleAPIs:23` is not a valid Android target platform.

I'm fairly new to eclipse I really want to know why.

Comment: Maybe some hints [here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cannot-compile-project-for-android-not-a-valid-android-target-platform/22349). Anyway, if you're using java, I'd suggest you use Android Studio, not eclipse.

Comment: Maybe right click the project properties->Builders->enable CDT Builder. Right about android Studio when Google finally release Android Studio 2.2 stable it will be better to use it, but right now is better eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add more code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!